For any row stochastic matrix M, is $P_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n M^i$ always converging?
I knew that in general, $M^n$ is not converging, but if $M$ is an irreducible aperiodic stochastic matrix, than one has
$$\lim_{n\infty} (M^n)_{i,j}=\pi_j$$
that is, each row of $M^n$ converge to the same vector $\pi$
However, the convergency of $M^n$ is in general not true, for example, for permutation matrix.
The question I am trying to ask is about the convergency of $P_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n M^i$ (since this seems to fixed the potential issue with permutation matrix).
I am not sure whether there exists other reducible matrix such that $P_n$ is not converging. I am looking for a proof for its convergency or an counterexample.

The matrix $P_n$ you've defined is called the Cesáro sum, and should rather be defined as $P_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} M^i$.
Let $\lvert\lvert{\cdot}||$ be the operator norm on matrices induced by the $\infty$-norm for vectors, i.e. the row summation norm. Then, for all $i$, $M^i$ is a stochastic matrix, which results in $||M^i|| = 1$. Thus, $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ||M^n|| \le 1 < \infty$, which is equivalent to the convergence of the Cesáro sum for linear operators on finite-dimensional spaces. Therefore, $P_n$ does indeed converge to a limit $P$ (w.r.t. all norms, since $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is finite-dimensional).

Thanks for the answer,  I also conject that P should have certainty structure: which is one of the following form
(1) homogenous (i.e., with $P_{ij}=\pi_j$ for all i ); (2)Indentity;   (3)  Block diagonized (up to permutation) of form (1) and （2).
Does this sounds true?
I have been suggesting that there might be some reducible or periodical matrix that might not have $P$ converge to the above form, but I could not found any counter example myself.

@YujieZhang Yes, it's true. First, consider an irreducible stochastic matrix $M$. Then, for any $i, \ j$, we find a $n > 0$ such that $M^n_{i,j} > 0$. This results in $P_{i,j} > 0$ for all $i, \ j$ if $P$ denotes the corresponding Cesáro sum. Taking any distribution $\gamma$, a simple calculation yields $(\gamma \cdot P) \cdot M = \gamma \cdot (P \cdot M) = \gamma \cdot P$, i.e. $\pi := \gamma \cdot P$ is the unique stationary distribution of the irreducible stochastic matrix $M$. Since $\gamma$ was taken arbitrarily, we can take $\gamma = e_j$ and receive $P_{ij} = \pi_j$ for all $i$.

My comment above marks off the case (1). For the case of a reducible matrix $M$, after permutation, we can assume that $M$ is a diagonal block matrix of irreducible stochastic matrices, each one corresponding to one of the communicating classes. Then, the Cesáro sum is a diagonal block matrix of the Cesáro sum of each of these irreducible submatrices. By my argument above, they are homogenous w.r.t. their limiting distribution. Thus, we have proven that, in general, (3) holds, which includes (2) since in that case, each state forms its own communicating class.

Thanks for the answer again,  but why we can assume M can be permutated as diagonal block matrix of irreducible stochastic matrices?  I thouthg permutation can only take any reducible matrix to be block upper triangular form.  I am not quite sure, how to view them as irreducible submatrices

@YujieZhang Okay you're right, my last answer only holds true if you assume that M can be deconstructed into communication classes. A counterexample for your proposition would be $M = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Since $M^n = M$, we have that $P = M$, which is neither the identity, homogenous nor a block diagonal matrix of those matrices.

Thanks for the example, but wouldn't this falls into the catogory (1)?
